# How to find log of "sum of two matrices"?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, logarithms, quantum-mechanics, entropy

I want to find **log (A + B )** where A and B are matrices.

The context is that I want to find the Von Neumann entropy which is given by:

$Entropy = - Trace [\rho log (\rho) ]$

where $\rho$ is a matrix.

Now, my problem is computing the V. N. entropy analytically when $\rho = \rho_{0} + \delta\rho$. For this I need to know $log (\rho_{0} + \delta\rho)$

Note that all $\rho$s are matrices.

Comment: Try the taylor series of $\log$

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Use the taylor series of ln(x+1) , now you have a way to compute it by setting ln(a+b) = ln(Q + 1) , Q = a + b - 1.

Comment: @SaurabhShringarpure I've seen that $\log (\boldsymbol A) = \mathrm {Log}(\boldsymbol I + \boldsymbol A) = \sum_1^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \boldsymbol A^n/n $ whenever $\|\boldsymbol A\| < 1$. This might be applicable, but stick to your text if the $\log$ was defined before.

Comment: So by doing that, I get:  $log(\rho_0 + \delta\rho)=log(\rho_0 + \delta\rho-1+1)=1 + [\rho_0 + \delta\rho-1]-\frac{[\rho_0 + \delta\rho-1]^2}{2}+...$

Comment: @SaurabhShringarpure Something like that, I think.

Comment: If $\rho_0$ is differentiable, you may want to rewrite $$\log(\rho_0 + \delta\rho) = \log(\rho_0) + \log(I + \delta\rho_0^{-1}\rho)$$ and you can apply the series expansion to the second term. (This is in particular probably more meaningful if $\rho_0$ is the "reference" and $\delta\rho$ is a small perturbation)